# Zoom In/Out effect in ImageView using seekbar

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, seekbar

hello i having one image within **ImageView** i want to make it Zoom In/Out using **SeekBar** without changing height width of **ImageView**.

[image]

when i move **SeekBar** to right side image would be Zoom In and while left it would Zoom Out.

thank you.

Comment: thnx @Arslan i accepted mostly proper answer.. well plz help in my above post.. nd i don't wnt pinch zoom..

Comment: You can edit this example : https://github.com/a85/WebComicViewer/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/ui/ZoomableImageView.java

Answer (score 1):

you can try & edit this code if you are willing to...

[pinch zoom Image view](https://github.com/akshatkumarvaish/TouchImageView)

I hope it helps..